# SQL - Avoid duplicates on the string with space in between

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table, where a value in one of the column-like, 'Test Record', 'TestRecord'. The combination of the Id and String column is a Unique key.

In my case, I should allow entering a value ('Test Record') with SPACE if already a record ('TestRecord') without SPACE.

Is there a way to restrict this by any constraints or any other approach?

Note: Space I have to consider only for a specific value, not for all the values in the column.

Comment: Look into Unique Constraints

Comment: Just to clarify your intention: you consider "test record" and "testrecord" as two different entries. So does SQL-Server. Simply add a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column and you're done.

Comment: If it's only for a specific value, this is starting to sound like an XY problem. That would mean that you can only ever have 1 row with this value in the entire? Is that really correct?

Comment: Yes, form a data point of view "test record and "testrecord" both are different. But from the user point of view, there is already a record in the system with "testrecord" so the system should not allow when a new(same) entry come with space.

Comment: yes @Larnu, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a persisted computed column on the table where the spaces are removed:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD YourColumnNoSpaces AS REPLACE(YourColumn,' ', '');
```

After that, add a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `UNIQUE INDEX` on the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_YourConstraint UNIQUE (YourColumnNoSpaces);
```

Based on the OP's new rules:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_YourIndex ON dbo.YourTable (YourColumnNoSpaces) WHERE YourColumnNoSpaces = 'TestRecord';
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this point in my question. Space I have to consider only for a specific value, not for all the values in the column.

Comment: Then use a filtered unique index instead? Changing the goal posts (so much) is really frowned upon after you start getting answers, @NaveenKumar .

Comment: I have updated the answer, though you should endeavour to give the *real* problem from the get go in questions, @NaveenKumar .

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu. Acknowledge your words.